# Event driven programming - event loops?

Tags: c++, events, synchronization, cross-platform, event-driven-design

I was just wondering, is any implementation of an event loop bound to platform specific code?

By event loop, I'm referring to a simple thread that is checking a queue, working with messages and dispatches appropriately to callbacks.

Because I simply don't see how I'd be able to write one without having to use for examples:

-A semaphore/mutex/event object/Sleep() [windows].

Which of course, the above are not the same for every operating system.

This is for C/C++ by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few portable, cross platform C++ frameworks have an event queue implemented, for example [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) Reactor framework. Another example is [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/).

Comment: Well of course - even C++11 has a multiplatform threading capability derived from boost - but aren't they just wrappers made with conditional compilation?

Comment: Certainly, a cross-platform C++ code working with threads and synchronization mechanisms will need to involve some conditional compilation. But is that a problem? You will not need to write a single `#ifdef` yourself, all the conditional code is wrapped inside the frameworks.

Comment: Nope, it isn't a problem. I just wanted to confirm my assumptions. Many thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you can see how to achieve what you need using C++11 features and/or BOOST, plus you know you can use C++11 and/or BOOST on your target platforms, then go for it!

Comment: My initial idea was to write it from scratch. Make my own event loop and do conditional compilation. So - something along the lines of writing my own event library so to say.